# How to update StreamProvider from a Firebase Authentication service?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider

I am following [this](https://github.com/nittinsharma37/firebase-authentication) example that implements **Firebase Authentication** in a Flutter app using Provider pattern.

The example uses `StreamProvider` defined as below in `main.dart`:

```
 StreamProvider<UserModel?>.value(
                  initialData: null,
                  catchError: (_, op) => null,
                  value: AuthService().user,
                ),
```

`UserModel` is defined as:

```
class UserModel {
  final String? userId;
  final String? name;
  final String? email;

  UserModel({
    this.userId,
    this.name,
    this.email,
  });
}
```

`AuthService` has these core methods (plus a few additional ones):

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //create user obj from firebase user

  UserModel? _userFromFirebase(User user) {
    return UserModel(userId: user.uid, name: user.displayName,email: user.email,);
  }

  //auth changes user stream

  Stream<UserModel?> get user {
    return _auth
        .authStateChanges()
        .map((User? user) => _userFromFirebase(user!));
  }
  

Future signUpWithEmailPassword({required String email, required String name, required String password}) async{
    try {
      UserCredential cred = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? user = cred.user;
      return _userFromFirebase(user!);
    } catch (e) {
       // ignore: avoid_print
       print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }

  }


  Future signinUsingEmailPassword(String email, String pass) async{

    try {
      UserCredential cred = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pass);
      User? user = cred.user;
      return _userFromFirebase(user!);
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }

  }
.
.
.
}
```

In the example, they are passing the user object to `HomePage`. I want to change that to use provider to access `userModel` instead. To achieve this I added provider to `HomePage`:

```
final userModel = Provider.of<UserModel?>(context);
```

This works for the cached user, i.e., when I start the app after a user has already signed in. But if I sign up/in for the first time, `userModel` is null.

I suspect that this because `StreamProvider` is not updated. Is there a way to update `StreamProvider` from the service on signin/signup?

[Full example](https://github.com/nittinsharma37/firebase-authentication)

Comment: If there is initially no user signed in, the `authStateChanges()` stream should receive a `null` value. But I don't think your code handles that case here: `.map((User? user) => _userFromFirebase(user!))` In fact, i'd expect the `user!` to raise an error when `user` is null.

Comment: That's fine. If there is no user signed in, user should be null. The problem is that user remains null after user signs in. If you then close the app and open it again, the user model is updated. My question is how to update it on sign in or sign up. that would require for provider to be updated from the service

Comment: `authStateChanges()` should automatically get a new event when the auth state changes. Hence my focus on the initial `null`, which your code doesn't handle.

Comment: That does not seem to be causing any problems. My issue is with userModel not being updated. I gave up on that and am getting user from service this way: User? getCurrentUser() {
    return _auth.currentUser;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Could not find an easy way to do what I asked, i.e., update `userModel` from `AuthService`, but I found an alternative solution that works just as well.

I've added this method to the `AuthService` and I can call this from anywhere without using a `provider`:

```
//return current user
  User? getCurrentUser() {
    return _auth.currentUser;
  }
```

I have updated GitHub example with this and other changes: [PR](https://github.com/nittinsharma37/firebase-authentication/pull/2)

I am happy to accept a better answer if any.